# Statistical view vs Materialized view

Tags: database

Statistical view:

This view collects the statistics about a table, like the number of records, maximum and minimum value of primary key. This helps in quick fetch of the data for an SQL query.

Materialized View:

This view is an ordinary view, just depicting the abstract data of the table as per the query the view is formed.

Now how and when we have to use this views in an application? How it can be handy in DBA point of view?

Comment: I don't think Oracle has anything like a "statistical view".

Comment: Indeed - but the question is only tagged "oracle".

Comment: I updated it ,.. thanks for noting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two are not really related at all.

Stats are collected ( or should be ) as part of everyday operation, they tell the query optimizer about the database, number of rows, distribution of values, etc. This helps the optimizer decide what is going to be the best query plan to use to get to the data "on disk".

A Materialized View is similar to a normal view ( eg, a "saved" query ) , however the results are stored, rather than the build query having to be re executed each time its called. There is various options for how to refresh the MV, on demand, each time the base tables are updated, etc.

Materialized views are often used for expensive queries where the results can be somewhat out of date. For example, if you had a table containing each sale made, you might create a MV which contains the total sales for each previous month.